# Hazelcast Predicate SQL into map

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet

I'm trying to build a method that deletes entries with attributes that are not null, but I keep failing in predicates and I don't know how to implement properly the predicate because hazelcast doesn't take "NOT NULL" or "IS NULL" as a where clause Any idea how can I find into the map the values I need to search to delete them?

the method

```
public int removeEntry(String CacheName, String claveReq, int id_interno_pe, String cod_nrbe_en, int num_sec_ac) {
    
    int counter = 0;
    IMap<String, ResponseSerializablePlus> map = clientInstance.getMap(CacheName);
    
    
//      Predicate claveReqQuery = Predicates.equal("claveReq", claveReq);
//      Predicate idInternoQuery = Predicates.equal("id_interno_pe", id_interno_pe);
//      Predicate codNrbeQuery = Predicates.equal("cod_nrbe_en", cod_nrbe_en);
//      Predicate numSecQuery = Predicates.equal("num_sec_ac", num_sec_ac);
//      Predicate query = Predicates.and(idInternoQuery,codNrbeQuery,numSecQuery);
    
    Predicate query = Predicates.sql("id_interno_pe IS NOT NULL"); 
    
    
    if (!map.isEmpty()) {
        for (ResponseSerializablePlus entry : map.values(query)) {
            System.out.println("Entry "+entry.toString()+" Found");
            map.delete(entry);
            
            counter++;
            
        }
        System.out.println("Map Size ->"+map.size());
        System.out.println("Deleted entries -> "+counter);
        return counter;
    }else {
        System.out.println("No matches");
        return 0;
    }
    }
```

the main class ResponseSerializablePlus

```
public class ResponseSerializablePlus implements IdentifiedDataSerializable{

private int id_interno_pe;
private String cod_nrbe_en;
private int num_sec_ac;
private int statusCode;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> headers;
private byte[] content;
public ResponseSerializablePlus(int id_interno_pe, String cod_nrbe_en, int num_sec_ac, int statusCode,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> headers, byte[] content) {
    this.id_interno_pe = id_interno_pe;
    this.cod_nrbe_en = cod_nrbe_en;
    this.num_sec_ac = num_sec_ac;
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.content = content;
}
public ResponseSerializablePlus() {
}
public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeInt(id_interno_pe);
    out.writeString(cod_nrbe_en);
    out.writeInt(num_sec_ac);
    out.writeInt(statusCode);
    out.writeObject(headers);
    out.writeByteArray(content);
    
}
public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
    this.id_interno_pe = in.readInt();
    this.cod_nrbe_en = in.readString();
    this.num_sec_ac = in.readInt();
    this.statusCode = in.readInt();
    this.headers = in.readObject();
    this.content = in.readByteArray();
    
}
public int getFactoryId() {
    return ResponseSerializablePlusFactory.FACTORY_ID;
}
public int getClassId() {
    return ResponseSerializablePlusFactory.RESPONSE_SERIALIZABLE_PLUS_CLASS;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ResponseSerializablePlus [id_interno_pe=" + id_interno_pe + ", cod_nrbe_en=" + cod_nrbe_en
            + ", num_sec_ac=" + num_sec_ac + ", statusCode=" + statusCode + ", headers=" + headers + ", content="
            + Arrays.toString(content) + "]";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed not supported, and it's document, along with the alternative option. Have a look here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/3cb8ce1fc3bb848aced6c87a30bf7b31aec16cf7/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/query/Predicates.java#L492-L497